# How to use my MPLAB C32 compiler in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, integration, mplab

Can anybody let me know the procedures to configure the build settings in Eclipse(Helios) IDE for MPLAB C32 Compiler from Microchip?

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer for your question, but it's an alternative. Now you can use [MPLab X](http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/family/mplabx/) that is based on Netbeans.